# why does javascript have a set of built in objects?

Tags: javascript, html, css

any particular reason?

Comment: Every language needs some objects, why wouldn't it have some?

Comment: You really want to implement your own `String`, `Array`, `Object`, `Date`, ... types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same reason any language has a standard library.  It doesn't have many, and the ones it does have are quite useful.

The only object types ECMAScript has are:

- Object
- Function
- Array
- String
- Boolean
- Number
- Date
- RegExp

along with the standard error objects.  Omitting even one of the above would significantly decrease the language's ease of use.

Note that the W3C APIs many people conflate JavaScript with are not built-in to the language.

Comment: Yeah, but Math isn't an object type.  It's a single object that's a "property of the global object", but most people would consider it a static class.

Comment: You are right, I misread this, I thought this is list of built-in objects, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially so that you don't have to write them.

Technically, some of the built in functions wrap functionality that you really couldn't do in JavaScript itself (i.e. build the dom--direct "Browser" interface).